# Override at least one method

Tags: c#, virtual, abstract, overriding

Let's suppose there is a following class:

```
public class foo{
    internal virtual object M1(/*args*/){return null;}
    internal virtual object[] M2(/*args*/){return null;}

    public SomeStruct SomeMethod(){
        return new SomeStruct
        {
            Obj = M1();
            ObjArr = M2();
        }
    }
}
```

Using the following struct:

```
public class SomeStruct
{
    public object Obj;
    public object[] ObjArr;
}
```

Is there a way to make sure (preferably at compilation) to force either at least one method or exactly one method of class foo to be overriden?

Before anybody says it - I know it's possible to use one method and check if the result is array (or IEnumerable) and then assign it to the right field, but that takes more time then just running empty methods. I'm just wondering if it's possible to do it that way.

Answer (score 3):

You could mark the methods `abstract`, and then you will be forced to implement both of the methods. This seems to be the most straightforward solution:

```
internal abstract object M1(/*args*/){return null;}
internal abstract object[] M2(/*args*/){return null;}
```

Another option, actually too complicated for this purpose, is to write a Roslyn code analyzer which will check the code and determines if it is valid.

As a side note: your fields should reside in the base class too. You could use generics if you want to make the types of them generic.

Comment: Yeah, but that would force implementation of both in child. While what's needed is one. As for generic - well yes, that is done in our project, but to make things simpler I didn't include it here.

Comment: Yes, that would be the consequence. You could return `null` or a default implementation from the second method if you want to.

Answer (score 2):

"No", basically. At least, not without writing your own custom code analyzer (perhaps via Roslyn), *and* considering what happens if `X : foo` overrides `M1`, and `Y : X` overrides `M2`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new method in your child class that hides the implementation of the base class, with the new return type. You cannot use virtual methods to overload a method like you're doing.Overloading of methods is done by changing the parameters, not the return type.

So either hide the parent method, in the child class, or create a method with another name.

Here is something that I can think of, just an example.

Run it here [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1SiHuG)

```
using System;

public class a
{
    public virtual object s(int a)
    {
        return a + 1;
    }
}

public class b : a
{
    public virtual object[] s(int a)
    {
        var arr = new object[]{a + 2};
        return arr;
    }
}

public class c : b
{
    private a A = new a();
    private b B = new b();
    public c()
    {
        print(2);
    }

    public void print(int a)
    {
        var result = A.s(1);
        Console.WriteLine("result : " + result);

        var resultB = B.s(1);
        //or resultB = base.s(1);

        foreach (var r in resultB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("result B : " + r);
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        c C = new c();
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not answer the question thou. Sure - it is possible to override return type, but in provided case all it does is it forces to check if return type is object or object[]. Which can take some time depending on object size. That and since base is returning object, and it is used in base - what's the point of overriding return type in the first place? Object[] is still an object.

Comment: I answered based on what I understood from your question and that's just an example based on the datatype you showed.